# How to make Apache .htaccess 404 addon domain subdomains/directories?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server

Forgive my inexperience with Apache, but I'm trying to set up my `.htaccess` file so that my 2 addon domains' subdomains and directories are inaccessible through the primary domain (i.e. they'll 404). In other words, `addon-domain-1.primary-domain.com` and `primary-domain.com/addon-domain-1` should both be inaccessible.

I think I'm on the right track, but my current implementation doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
# Redirect to www/https
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^primary-domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.primary-domain.com/$1 [R=301]

# Block addon domain directories
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addon-domain-1\.primary-domain\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addon-domain-2\.primary-domain\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?primary-domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/addon-domain-1/(.*) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/addon-domain-2/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]
```

This `.htaccess` file is placed in the root directory (`primary-domain.com`)

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving it by doing something similar to @anubhava's answer (with a few changes), and most importantly putting these changes inside the addon domains' `.htaccess` files as well.

Primary domain:

```
# Forward to www/HTTPS
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^primary-domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.primary-domain.com/$1 [R=301]

# Block addon domain directories
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(addon-domain-1|addon-domain-2)\.primary-domain\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(addon-domain-1|addon-domain-2)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]
```

Addon domain 1:

```
# Forward to www/HTTPS
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^addon-domain-1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.addon-domain-1.com/$1 [R=301]

# Block addon domain directories
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?addon-domain-1\.primary-domain\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/addon-domain-1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setup block rule like this:

```bash
# Block addon domain directories
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www|addon-domain-1|addon-domain-2)\.)?primary-domain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(addon-domain-1|addon-domain-2)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Really appreciate that (way better readability), I was able to do that but unfortunately it still allows me to access `addon-domains.primary-domain.com` and `primary-domain.com/addon-domains`. I just have this .htaccess file in the root folder, do I need it somewhere else as well maybe?

Comment: Update to my comment, I made a few changes to the code but overall very similar and put it inside the addon `.htaccess`s as well

Comment: What are `DocumentRoot` values for primary and addon domains?

Comment: Not positive on that one, there's nothing explicitly set. As per my answer though, I was able to do it by putting similar rules inside the addon domains' `.htaccess`

Comment: `Not positive on that one`: Every domain or subdomain is supposed to have one `DocumentRoot` in apache. Try asking from your server admin what it is and update here.